# PHP preg_replace function error with special characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use preg_replace function to parse this table in a Html page :

```
Tuition.    $13,140   $13,167    $13,167    
Books       $996      $1,176     $1,176
```

Because of table tags I got "Unknown modifier '`t`' " error and I changed '`/ /`' with '`~ ~`'.

Still I have problem, the function is not changing the text. I think the problem with '`$`' dollars sign in the text, how can I skip it? I tried to do but I couldn't.

Here is my code :

```
$price = $html->find('div[id=divctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucInstitutionMain_ctl00] table[class=tabular]');

        $price1=$price[0];
        $show=$price1;

        $ch="~".$show->children(1)->children(0)->children(1)."~";
        $show=preg_replace($ch,' ',$show, 1);
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `preg_quote` will escape the pattern so the `preg_replace` works, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do with the table?

Comment: Yes preg_quote also skips '< >' character and it breaks my table, I want to keep HTML tags, I just want to skip dollar sign.

I am trying to transfer data from one website to another.

Comment: Show us what is in `$ch`

Comment: $ch will be in a for loop and each time it will keep data on the table. When you made $ch="Tuition and fees" there is no problem but when you out $ch=$13,140 it is not working

Comment: I just mentioned dollar sign but the problem may be with comma as well, or another reason. I am not good at regex I just started learning and I need to fix this for my project.

Comment: Can't you just use an HTML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this : `$show=preg_replace(str_replace('$','\$',$ch),' ',$show, 1);`
If you can't use preg_quote and have multiple escape ( in this case $ is your problem), you could put your special character in an array and filter from it.